# Is there a way to push the ArrayList Data to a ConcurrentDictionary without using loop in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, devexpress

I have some rows on a data grid, which Ι can select based upon "checkbox tick" and then data get stored in ArrayList.

Now using data in Αrraylist, Ι want to push data into a ConcurrentDictionary, to sort data based upon key and value.

and then based upon it Ι want to generate data on grid secondary Grids.

I have already achieve this using a for loop, but Ι want to do it faster .

please suggest something ....

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridCheckMarksSA.Selection.Count; i++)
{
         List<OptionDecoderProRpt> _LoopCheck = new List<OptionDecoderProRpt>();
         checkedRows.Add((OptionDecoderProRpt)gridCheckMarksSA.GetSelectedRow(i));
         //this if else is to filter out key 
         if (ShortNameCheck.Contains(checkedRows[i].clsUnderlying_Spot.ShortName))
            {

            }
        else
            {
                ShortNameCheck.Add(checkedRows[i].clsUnderlying_Spot.ShortName);
                temp = checkedRows[i].clsUnderlying_Spot.ShortName;
            }
        // getting data into Dictionary.
        if (checkRowsDic.ContainsKey(checkedRows[i].clsUnderlying_Spot.ShortName))
            {
                checkRowsDic[checkedRows[i].clsUnderlying_Spot.ShortName].Add(checkedRows[i]);
            }
       else
            {
                _LoopCheck = new List<OptionDecoderProRpt> { checkedRows[i] };
                checkRowsDic.TryAdd(checkedRows[i].clsUnderlying_Spot.ShortName, _LoopCheck);
            }
}
```

I am expective a way to get data into `checkRowsDic` (`Dictionary`) from `gridCheckMarksSA.Selection` (`ArrayList`) without using loop.